# WCF Getting "The primary signature must be encrypted." from FaultContract with ProtectionLevel.None

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wcf-faults

I have an existing asp.net application that talks to load balanced wcf services (iis hosted, in app pool running under account configured as servicePrincipalName, etc.). The wcf services return a few custom faults, all defined with FaultContract(typeof(x), ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None) -- these services are not exposed to the public. The client uses the 'service reference' generated classes to access the services.

This has worked fine but now, with the latest code base, we are getting "The primary signature must be encrypted." exceptions on the client when the service returns one of these faults. The service code and configuration is unchanged (at least the legacy parts that generate the faults). The client side service reference generated code appears the most changed (it often gets removed and recreated).

The security configuration is unchanged for over a year. All the updates are pretty current. We've tested this in three environments and as soon as we deploy the new code base, the faults start generating exceptions. Seems like it has to be in the generated classes but they are generated by Visual Studio so it is very perplexing.

Does this sound familiar to anyone? Any suggestions?

Update: Removing the ProtectionLevel attribute and allowing it to default makes the problem 'go away', but I am curious why specifying None causes it to fail. Perhaps it conflicts with the default level of the operation contract or service contract, but those values have not changed in the past year so that doesn't explain why what had worked now doesn't.

Update: For what it is worth, this change in code gen happened between 2.0.50727.3053 and 2.0.50727.3082 (according to the runtime-version comment in the generated code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't experienced this problem myself, but my questionn is: why on earth do you specify a "ProtectionLevel=None" in your fault contract? Any particular reason for that?

If not, I'd strongly recommend not specifying that at all - the default is ProtectionLevel=EncryptAndSign and that's usually your best bet all around. Try it, unless you have a very strong and explicit reason against it.

Marc

Comment: That's a good question. It was done over two years ago in response to problems with custom faults returning "An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party" exceptions. Setting the protection level to None "made it work" back then and seeing how it was an internal service the idea of not having the overhead seemed OK. Being so new to WCF, and WCF being so new, and being under deadlines we were happy it worked and moved on... then forgot all about it.